# Clarification on the security of storing database passwords in database.yml

Tags: sql-server, security, ruby-on-rails-4, credentials

Application:  Building a small application for maintaining schedules of activity.  It queries a MSSQL database.  Storage for schedules is written to the MSSQL DB as well.

I've reviewed a large number of posts on stack overflow as well as googled extensively on securing the database.yml file.  Maybe it's just me but I'm left with some major questions still.

1)  Why exactly is storing my password in plain text in database.yml insecure?  Is it because that method of storing password information is insecure in itself?  Or is it because when publishing to a git repository you may inadvertently publish your database passwords in plain text?

2)  If storing passwords in plain text under root/config/database.yml is insecure, why do I see a number of references to creating another yml file in the same directory to store the password?  I see that some people are setting up a config.yml and creating global variables that can be used in database.yml.  If this is more secure, why?
http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file

My gut feeling is I'm missing some important knowledge on how to properly secure my database credentials.  I'm really looking for an exhaustive explanation on what needs to be done to secure my credentials for sql.

Edit:  I just wanted to update the context of this.  I understand the need to encrypt passwords out of plain text - but I didn't understand why it seemed OK to store plain text password in other YML files.